# how to evict hazelcast caches manually or on a future timestamp

Tags: spring, hazelcast, distributed-cache

I have hazelcast running in kubernetes in a cluster.

I want to make sure, once someone changes a thing lets say in a PriceCatalog,
hazelcast must be evicted immediately(or configurable) of the all the caches related.

Imagine there is price change on a product, which will take place in 24 hours.

Waiting Time2Live is not an option, there can be time windows that old price will be applied, which will be broken.

Is there a way to evict the caches on given timestamp?
Or easily manually evict all the caches related?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you saying changes in one cache should trigger eviction of related data in other caches or if are you saying if something changes in the database then that should trigger eviction of data from Hazelcast caches? In your example, where is PriceCatalog - in a cache in Hazelcast or in a db?

Comment: basically I'd like to achieve the first question in the last sentance:
"a way to evict the caches on given timestamp"

i.e not an interval of time2live but a concrete time,
sort of a future scheduling task out of the box

Answer (score 1):

You can do better than just evicting entities on a change by using Cache-Ahead.

I suggest you read this post where I explain [how to set up a cache that's always in sync with the database](https://jet-start.sh/blog/2020/07/16/designing-evergreen-cache-cdc).